# Who was the person that Vilgefortz killed at the end of the Battle of Sodden?

Tags: the-witcher

In the final episode of the Season 1, Vilgefortz stands as one of the mages opposing Nilfgaard. During the battle of Sodden, he duels Cahir and looses, however, he manages to escape. We can see him later stumbling on a group of dead Nilfgaardian troops... and one man who seems to know him. That person calls to Vilgefortz for help, but he instead grabs a mace and kills the wounded man.

Who was that victim? Was it one of the Nilfgaardian mages? One of the defenders that somehow witnessed Vilgefortz humiliation?

Comment: I have a feeling they did particularly bad job at depicting Vilgefortz, and may have troubles later with reconciling it with future events. Basically they shown him as total wuss, and gonna make up some reasons while he's gonna turn into incredible badass that he should be all the time.

Comment: @Mithoron I believe he will have his "Anakin to Vader" transformation yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It was one of the defenders

That mage had managed to kill all of the Nilfgaardian soldiers he was fighting but was wounded in doing so. As you already stated, Vilgefortz killed him rather than help him.

As to why he did that, well that might be a spoiler for some so I'm going to go ahead and mark it as one.

That scene is essentially meant to show

> that Vilgefortz is a turncoat and is actually working with Nilfgaard.

This is also in line with Vilgefortz's character in books, in which he does the exact same thing.

Comment: Why did Cahir attack Vilgefortz so brutally, then, and why did Vilgefortz say the things he did to him?

Comment: @Adamant This is actually quite ambiguous even in the book, but my guess would be that his cooperation was quite secret and Cahir simply wouldn't know and treat him as a regular enemy. Another possibility is that Vilgeforz (at least later in the series) wants Ciri for herself, so Cahir is an obstacle.

Comment: @Adamant And also take into account that the series did a pretty poor job in developing side-characters and plots so ...

Answer (score 0):

He was one of the defenders. Vilgefortz killed him not because he witnessed the latter's humiliation, the mage was too occupied fighting the Nilfgaardian soldiers, was wounded and asked Vilgefortz for help. Vilgefortz killed him because he is a traitor and has always been an ally of Emyhr.

Comment: This is a bit unclear; when you say "killed him because he is a traitor," it sounds like you're saying the defender is a traitor.